# File corruption on downloading docx using phpWord - javascript client side issue

Tags: php, content-type, docx, phpword

I'm using phpWord to create a word document on the fly in a php script that is called using XMLHttpRequest. I'm trapping the response to the request, and then attempting to prompt the user to download or open the file.  My phpWord code creates the file OK (I can open the file on the server), and the browser prompts the user to open or save the file, but the file that is downloaded is corrupted somehow. It gives an error like "We're sorry. We can't open results.docx because we found a problem with its contents".

On the server side I have this code:

```
...
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
flush();
readfile($filename);
```

On the client side I have this code:

```
function getDOC()
{
    url='services/doc_search_results_service.php/';

    var req = null;
    var postParms = '';

    req = new XMLHttpRequest
    if ( req )
    {
        req.open( 'POST', url, true );
        req.setRequestHeader( "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
        req.setRequestHeader( "Content-length", postParms.length );
        req.setRequestHeader( "Connection", "close" );
        req.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if ( req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200 )
            {
                downloadDOC( "results.docx", req.responseText );
            }
        }
        req.send( postParms );
    }
}

function downloadDOC(filename, text) 
{
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
    document.body.appendChild(pom);
    pom.click();
    document.body.removeChild(pom);
}
```

Would love to know if anyone can spot where I'm going wrong. I'm not an expert in php nor javascript, so any help would be gratefully received.  FWIW I think it may be to do with headers.  I'm also guessing that it may well be a client side problem as the file is create OK on the server side.

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: try diff the two files (on server and what you download), maybe you'll see something (eg truncated content, dunno)

Comment: Do you really need it to be a POST request? While this is possible with ajax(in modern browsers) if it was a GET request you could just do `window.location = url;`

Comment: musa and mightypork thanks for your suggestions. It's late here now (and I've spent too much time staring at a screen already), so will try them first thing tomorrow am. Thanks Chris

Comment: @musa - worked like a charm, Thankyou!   It didn't need to be POST - I was just (lazily) re-using some other code. As I said in the question, I'm no javascript expert either (evidently).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Musa for the suggestion to use 'GET' rather than 'POST' which worked perfectly.

As @Musa suggested, the client-side javascript in this example should be:

```
window.location = 'services/doc_search_results_service.php/';
```

Which replaces all the javascript quoted in my original question.

Note - I'm not sure what the correct answer would have been if it had not been possible to use GET for some reason.